# rsync --ignore-missing-args not working

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync actually inside loop to backup a list of directories from remote.
I just want to ignore if src directory do not exists.
I got from most of the forums that `--ignore-missing-args` would work.

But in my case `rsync` is constantly failing giving `no such file or directory`.

this is the command I tried:

```
rsync -avl --ignore-errors --ignore-missing-args \
      --rsync-path="sudo rsync"\
      node1.dataqa.flytxt.com:/var/www/cgi-bin \
      /tmp/akhil/82/configurations/node1.dataqa.flytxt.com`
```

I also added `--ignore-errors`, but that also not working!

**Error:**

```
Welcome to Flytxt cluster. Authorized access only. Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized user !!!
receiving incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/var/www" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 8 bytes  received 78 bytes  172.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1650) [Receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

Comment: You can ignore the errors, but you cannot go forward if there is not an accessible (readable)  directory `/var/www` on the `node1.dataqa.flytxt.com` from who/where you are running the `rsync` command...

Comment: okay  I undestood

Comment: In the hope it may help. By the way, I am still wondering what benefits are gained by using `--rsync-path =" sudo rsync "` instead of directly at the beginning `sudo rsync -avl ...`. Note that in general for commands preceded by sudo it is better to specify the full path (eg `/usr/bin/rsync`) to avoid any security flaws. Good luck and let us know how it proceeds.

Comment: I donot know exact working, but path="sudo rsync" makes sure I have enough permission to access files on remote server. Also sudo rsync don't works for me since root user ssh is disabled on remote server.

Comment: Ok time to clean up! Please [edit] you question. Specify better the situation, Machine1 (from when you start the command), Machine2 where it is executed, Machine3(probably=Machine2) where are the files to be copied... Then what you want to do. What you obtain and what you would like to obtain. (this you have already done).
**Note** `--ignore-errors         delete even if there are I/O errors`, maybe not what you wanted. Moreover, use the option `-n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made` to do your tests. PS> I did not understand what you mean with _inside loop_.

Comment: If I correctly undestand you, you want to do  a local backup on a remote machine using a command from your _actual_ machine (let we call it _home_ machine). If you are able to do locally on the remote machine, then you can do a script and run from _home_ via ssh. If the remote rsync needs sudo privileges you need to give those privileges to the script. Then you can call the script via ssh that it will be possible because a non root command.

Comment: Give some feedback, maybe you will help somebody else too...

Comment: Yes I solved my problem by checking manually whether the specific file exists before rsync. Rsync basically do not ignore the src file even with the option if the specified src path's parent directory donot exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, IMHO, `rsync` has a not-so-intuitive set of options. It really has a **full set** of options that let you do almost anything, but it can be complex to use, especially at first. It may be helpful to think about when and what it was used for. It has options only for files, or only for directories, symlinks or hardlinks... When you have enough time, take a look at `man rsync`. It may be interesting to understand its potential ... The purpose of my suggestion is not to learn all the options, but just to get an idea of what and how. When you need it, you'll go find what you need.